# Matlab - How to plot 2d Quadratic equation

Tags: matlab, plot, data-science

I'm a newbie to matlab. Now I'm trying to plot a 2d quadratic equation. Such as ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx + ey + f = 0.
The way I try is to use

```
x = linspace(-1,2,100);
```

and transform the equation to y = "use x to represent y"

then `plot(x,"use x to represent y")`

But since that y has a square(which means y = "square root of something").

So it wont show the negative part of y.

Is there any efficient way to plot such quadratic equation?

Comment: for example: `ezplot('3.*x.^2 + y.^2 + 2.*x.*y + 4.*x + 2.*y -10',[-10,10,-10,10])`

Comment: a,b,c,d,e,f in my case is a variable. I don't think it could use ezplot

Comment: sure it can, you just need to change it into a string using   `num2str()` , so your call will look something like `ezplot([num2str(a), '*x^2+',num2str(b),'y.^2+'])` etc... 
 @Pwan.

Comment: the code you wrote doesn't work? @itzikBenShabat

Comment: it was meant for you to edit, so i wrote the full solution as an answer @Pwan

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this

```
a = 1;
b=1;
c=1;
d=1;
e=1;
f=1;
ezplot([num2str(a),'*x.^2 +',num2str(b),' *y.^2 + ',num2str(c),'*x.*y + ',num2str(d),'*x + ',num2str(e),'*y -',num2str(f)],[-10,10,-10,10])
```